# Maven - do a mvn install on local artifact when packaging

Tags: maven

i have a maven project which has some local artifacts as dependencies.

When I have to package my main application, i have to do a `mvn install` command on my local repositories before, which is quite annoying and easy to forget.

Is there a way to tell maven to install local repositories when packaging the main one?

Comment: You can wrap up everything in a parent pom, and then, by performing a build of the parent project, you will trigger the build of every component.

Comment: this is perfect! Thanks, if you put it as an answer i will accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be to wrap up all your components into a pom project.

When building a parent pom maven automatically triggers a build of all the sub-modules.